# Is it more efficient to set the size of a vector up front?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

If you are able to, is it more efficient to set the size of a vector up front? I intend to push_back values.

Comment: Time efficient? Space efficient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `.push_back()` to store values, it is **incorrect** to "set the *size* of the vector up front" using the `.resize()` member function. Rather, you would set the *capacity* of the vector up front using the `.reserve()` member function.

Here are three correct approaches:

```
// 1) Do nothing initially, use .push_back
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1); v.push_back(2);

// 2) Set the capacity initially, use .push_back
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(2);
v.push_back(1); v.push_back(2);

// 3) Set the size initiallly, use subscripts
std::vector<int> v(2); // Set the size in construction
v.resize(2);             // OR set the size by a call to .resize()
v[0] = 1; v[1] = 2;
```

Yes, the 2nd approach is usually more size- and time-efficient than the first.

The 2nd approach is sometimes more time-efficient than the 3rd. Or not. You should measure it to see if it even matters.

Comment: `size` -> `resize` to actually set the size.

Comment: @Robᵩ - After going over "More effective STL" of Scott Meyers , Item 14 , I think that the second approach you have suggested is the best - isn't it ?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's generally a little more efficient. Don't expect a huge improvement, but at worst it's harmless (obviously assuming you only reserve the space you actually need).

For a rather unusual situation, it may improve both the time taken *and* the amount of space consumed. When you use `push_back` it'l increase the size by some multiplicative factor when you run out of space, but if you use `reserve`, it may allocate exactly the amount you need instead of rounding up to the next multiple of whatever factor it uses.

Comment: Harmless? `vec.reserve( 1024 * 1024 * 100 );`

Comment: @Konrad I guess you would know it would break upfront rather than in a half hour if that is how much space you needed reserved.

Comment: @Konrad: Yes -- if you're going to use that space anyway, getting it with `reserve` will be at least as efficient as doing it with several reallocations.

Comment: @Joe: You'd typically need a reasonably old computer to expect that to break. Assuming that's a `vector<int>`, you're talking about ~400 megabytes -- hardly a strain when even low-end systems now typically have at least 2 gigabytes of RAM.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I am aware but I was just responding to the point that I believe Konrad was making. However, that is still easily possible to break on mobile and embedded devices.

Comment: `400 megabytes` are not even RAM; it is virtual memory,which means, if a system has 2 GB of RAM, the sum of all memory allocated to all processes running on the system will most likely be greater than 2 GB.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it normally will as it reserves space (capacity) therefore there are less memory allocations and moving of data since a vector guarantees its data to be stored contiguously.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it would be more efficient if you could reserve the right amount of data up front.
When the vector reaches its capacity, it will have to allocate new storage, there will be a performance hit then.