# change my recursive solution into a dynamic programming solution

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic

here I am trying to convert my recursive solution into a dynamic solution  but I am getting problem in converting. I am trying to count minimum possible coin to make value. what I am doing is I am taking all possible coin and putting inside a vector and finally in main function I will find and minimum of my vector and that will be my answer

```
int rec(vector<int>coins,int n,int sum,int counter)
{
     if(sum==0)
     {
         return 1;
     }
     if(n==0)
     {
         return 0;
     }
     int total=rec(coins,n-1,sum,counter);
     if(sum-coins[n-1]>=0)
     {
         total+=rec(coins,n,sum-coins[n-1],counter+1);
         if(sum-coins[n-1]==0)
         {
              vec.push_back(counter+1);
         }
     }
     return total;
}
```

Comment: Depending on the values of the coins, you won't need dynamic programming as the greedy choice suffices.

Answer (score 0):

you should first try to solve this type of problems by yourself.

BTW:

```
#define BIG 2147483647

int min_coin(int *coins, int m, int desire_value)
{
    int dp[desire_value+1];

    dp[0] = 0;
 
    for (int i=1; i<=desire_value; i++)
        dp[i] = BIG;
 
    for (int i=1; i<=desire_value; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
          if (coins[j] <= i)
          {
              int diff = dp[i-coins[j]];
              if (diff != BIG && diff + 1 < dp[i])
                  dp[i] = diff + 1;
          }
    }
   
      if(dp[desire_value]==BIG)
        return -1;
   
    return dp[desire_value];
}
```

you can easily convert `dp` and `coins` to vector. vector is like array.(beware for allocate vector for dp you should reserve space in vector see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457571/how-to-set-initial-size-of-stdvector/11457629).)

Comment: thanks for your answer but I can do easily the solution you have provided...but my concern is too adjust counter in my dp solution